Normal map reflection
hi I have a problem with blender 4.2 I animated an object so that it can rotate on itself but the normal map rotates at the same time and gives a weird result, is there anyone who has a solution please?
this is a footage of my problem :
https://youtu.be/-ITkBf6orJc

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

@TheValox63 can you follow the instructions in the link Instructions for sharing. Blend-exchange is specifically designed to share blender files on this site, and you also didn't pack all the images into your file.

@TheValox63 the problem was not the Normal Map node settings (it's in Tangent Space mode which is OK) but the Image Texture node settings   ;)

I closed the question because this post in itself lacks details like for example there is no file attached to the post.

Switch your Image Texture from sRGB to Non-Color:


thank you that fixed my problem !

@TheValox63 Hello and welcome. Please don't just reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead upvote the post that helped you. If you feel it completely solved your issue consider marking it as accepted.

And as a rule of thumb: any image texture that isn't used as base color in your shader should be set to "Non-Color" Color Space. That includes normal maps, height, bumb, specular, metallic, etc...

@TheValox63 If this solved your problem could you please click the checkmark to the left of moonboots' post so we can close the question.
